# swift/alamofire/api token/ Missing required parameter: grant_type

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter

I'm attempting to create TwitterSearcher.

My Conditions are

- Using app-only authentication
- standard search API
- Using Alamofire, SwiftyJSON

As some of you know, you need to get a token in order to access Twitter before searching for tweets.

I'm pretty new to using API itself but I barely implemented some code.
However, I came across an error response below on the way to get a token.

```
{
  "errors" : [
    {
      "code" : 170,
      "label" : "forbidden_missing_parameter",
      "message" : "Missing required parameter: grant_type"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already tried some ways referring to other articles, let's say

- changing param to ["payload" : "grant_type=client_credentials"]
- eliminate "content_type" from Header

Although I haven't grabbed the meanings of these two, the error is still going on.

```swift
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

protocol SearchUserApi {
    func getToken()
    func getTweets(content: String)
}

class APIOperator: SearchUserApi {

     var accessToken: String?
     let tokenApi = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"
     let api = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
     let consumerKey = "---"
     let consumerSecret = "---"



    func getToken() {
        let credentials = "\(consumerKey):\(consumerSecret)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let headers = [
            "Authorization" : "Basic \(credentials)",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        ]
        let params: [String : AnyObject] = ["grant_type": "client_credentials" as AnyObject]


        Alamofire.request(
            tokenApi,
            method: .post,
            parameters: params,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: headers
            )
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                guard let object = response.result.value else {
                    print("Getting token is failed")
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(object)
                print(json)
        }


    }

    func getTweets(content: String) {
       print("not yet")
    }  
}
```

Hope you guys will help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `URLEncoding.httpBody` instead of  `JSONEncoding.default`

OR

Alamofire directly support Basic auth

see this

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#authentication

Here is sample code from docs

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .forSession)

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
    .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

and use  `authorizationHeader` as request header in alamofire

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thank you for the comment. i actually read Github but i couldn't understand where parameters and headers went to. In case of using `authorizationHeader`, you don't have to add Authorization, content_type and grant_type like above? And user and password imply consumerKey and Secret in this case? Because it is app-only.

Comment: BTW `URLEncoding.httpBody` apparently works!! Thanks.

Comment: @lyn I have seen other question and found that grant_type should be passed as string not as HTTP Body.  Please mark my answer as accepted if  it is helpful.